# Set unbound combo box to match on full string for not in list event

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an unbound combo box that gets it's row source values using a select query in VBA. The values shown are filtered by other selections on the form. If a value entered is not on the list I have a prompt to ask the user if they would like to add a new record. So far this has worked without any problems.

I overlooked one issue. If the "new" item is a partial match the selection defaults to the partial match entry.  (Ex. I want to add part 4321437 but part 4321437-01 is already present.) How can I get the field to match using the full field?

I have tried playing with auto expand, allow value list edits, show only row source values, and inherit value list. Nothing seems to stop it from auto-filling. I have also tried clicking out of the field versus tabbing out.

If I remove my for key-down event that displays the list options with the arrow keys, it works. However, the customer would like to keep that feature.

Is there a way to have both?

Comment: you can disable auto expand property. which will stop the auto selection/prediction. have you tried that?

Comment: If you know of anything that *doesn't* work (you tried a method but it didn't produce the results you want), include that in your question too so others know not to try or suggest it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to have both. In my Key Down Event, I check if the down arrow is pressed. If it is, I display the drop down menu.

```
If KeyCode = vbKeyDown Then
    Me![cboNewPart].Dropdown
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Thinking outside the box, perhaps consider using a **TextBox** in place of a **ComboBox**.

This way, using the `AfterUpdate` event, you would have full control over how the entered value is handled: test for a match in your dataset using a simple query and branch accordingly.

You could even cycle through existing options by successively populating the TextBox with existing values from your dataset on the `KeyDown` event triggered by the arrow keys.

Comment: Interesting thought, I like it, however the drop down gives the user a quick look of options available. So far they can still click on the drop down arrow to make a selection or type it in if they are already familiar with the data.